# Change Ansible module based on variable or group

Tags: ansible

There are many Ansible Network modules (for example: ios_user, asa_user, nxos_user) which share the same (or similar enough) interfaces. Currently, my playbook has to conditionally execute tasks based on the host's group or variables. This leads to a lot of duplicated code as the only real difference between the tasks is the module name.

**Is there a way to select the module to be run based on group or variable values** without adding extra tasks, roles, or playbooks?

*For example, this is how the playbook currently looks:*

```
- hosts: ios
  tasks:
    ios_user:
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
      ...
- hosts: asa
  tasks:
    asa_user:
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
      ...
- hosts: nxos
  tasks:
    nxos_user:
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
      ...
```

*I'd love to have something like this:*

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    {{ module_name }}:
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
      ...
```

I swear I saw some feature like this in passing, but I'm having a hard time finding it again. Along with version 2.5 making netconf_cli a first-class connection type, this would solve a large number of problems and inconveniences in our org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on @030's answer, here's how you can use variables for modules:

1. You need to group the target hosts in groups, for the example I'm using `server1.example.com` as member of `hosts1` group and `server2.example.com` as member of `hosts2` group.
2. You create group variables:

   - group_vars/hosts1
   - group_vars/hosts2

Both files contain a variable named `module` with different value, in the test I use `stat`.

3. Your playbook will look like this:

`test.yml`

```
---
 - hosts: all        
   user: me        
   tasks:
     - name: test module variables
       action: "{{ module }} path=/home/me/myfile"
```

The result of the play:

```
[me@myserver]$ ansible-playbook test.yml -i test

PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************
ok: [server1.example.com]
ok: [server2.example.com]

TASK [test module variables] **************************************************************
ok: [server1.example.com]
ok: [server2.example.com]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
server1.example.com        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server2.example.com        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: "Action" is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to declare group and host vars http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html

> ```
> group_vars/
>    group1                 # here we assign variables to particular groups
>    group2                 # ""
> host_vars/
>    hostname1              # if systems need specific variables, put them here
>    hostname2              # ""
> ```

Comment: While this is correct, and thanks for the help, this doesn't answer the question. I understand how to add group, variables, and group variables. What I want is to execute a different module *based* on those group variables.

Comment: module or role?

Comment: @030 Module, like `yum` or `apt`.  See the accepted answer.